# Problem in porting desktop applicaiton to 64 bit that supports Microsoft Accessibility

Tags: windows, winapi, accessibility

I'm porting a desktop application that supports Microsoft Accessibility from 32-bit to 64-bit. This application has lots of custom controls. While calling `NotifyWinEvent()`:

```
/*Pseudocode*/
MYSTRUCT *ptr;
allocate and assign data to ptr;
Call NotifyWinEvent(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, hwnd, OBJID_CLIENT, (long)ptr).
```

The code extracts the pointer in an `IAccessible` implemented method and uses it:

```
/* pseudocode */

TDMETHODIMP CMSAAMyProxy::get_accRole( VARIANT varChild, VARIANT *pvarRole )
{
    if (VT_I4 == varChild.vt)
    {
        MYSTRUCT *ptr = (MYSTRUCT *)varChild.lVal;
        /* Use the ptr here */
    }
}
```

Such code is written in many files. While the above code is running well on 32-bit, it's crashing on 64-bit due to pointer truncation.

Is there any alternate API I can use to resolve this issue?

Comment: To solve this issue, you will have to take a step back, and properly analyze, what the issue is. The issue here is, that your implementation uses an API outside its documented contract. The *idChild* argument to [NotifyWinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-notifywinevent) carries an object **ID**, not a pointer. That's what needs to be fixed. There is no alternate API that can reliably be used outside its specification.

Comment: MSAA Object IDs are not large enough to carry 64-bit pointers. To pass a pointer to `NotifyWinEvent()`, you would have to store the pointer in the passed `HWND` via `SetWindowsLongPtr()` or `SetProp()`, and then WinEvent callbacks can retrieve the pointer from the `HWND`. Obviously, that will not work across process boundaries, though. The real question is, why doesn't your `CMSAAMyProxy` class hold the pointer it needs? Why are you trying to pass the pointer via `NotifyWinEvent()` at all? It is not meant for that purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree with your point, NotifyWinEvent shouldn't be passed a pointer. It's a decade old code, I guess. I have to check alternate solution anyways. I think a 32 bit of pointer's hash can help here.